# In how many ways can a coat be chosen such that exactly one person picks up the correct coat?

Tags: probability, permutations

There are n people at a party. At the end they each take a coat at random. 
a) How many ways can coats be chosen such that no person picks up their own coat/what is the probability that no person picks up their own coat?

b) In how many ways can a coat be chosen such that at least one person picks up the correct coat?

c)In how many ways can a coat be chosen such that exactly one person picks up the correct coat?

For part a) I have used d(n)=n!*sum from k=0 to infinity((-1)^k)/k!), however am unsure on how to calculate the probability that no person picks up their own coat, and how to go about answering b) and c).

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Not enough information given.  You didn't say if all the coats belong to the party guests and if each person at the party brought exactly 1 coat to it.  For example, what if n=3 so call them persons A,B, and C.  A brought 2 coats, B didn't bring any, and C brought exactly 1?  Also what if coats are already there before the party starts?

Comment: All the coats do belong to the party guests and each person only brought one coat.

Comment: Still not enough information given.  What if people at the party sell and/or trade their coat for a non coat item so then they came to the party owning 1 coat but then left owning none?  Also another party guest may then own 2 coats.

Comment: Are you maybe over complicating things? This is something I tend to do which is why I'm in the situation that I'm in!

Comment: Well if you want an exact answer then you should be exact in your question, otherwise any person that answers may have to make assumptions.  Obviously what I am speculating could happen in real life (perhaps someone sees a really cool coat and buys it at the party).

Answer (score 1):

If the coats are distributed at random so everybody has one coat then there are $n!$ possible distributions.

For (a) everybody having the wrong coat, you are looking at [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) and you have your expression, though this should be over a finite sum:  $ \displaystyle d(n)=n!\sum_0^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ though I prefer to use $d(n)=\text{round}\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]$.  The probability is then $\frac{d(n)}{n!}$.

For (b) at least one person having the correct coat, this is the complement event of (a) and so very easy.

For (c) exactly one person having the correct coat, to count the possibilities you need to identify the individual with the correct coat and then count the derangements among the others, making the probability $\frac{n\,d(n-1)}{n!}$

Comment: Thanks for your help. So for c) the number of ways is d(n-1)? I'm still uncertain as to how to find the number of ways for b) - the complement event refers to the probability?

Answer (score 0):

a1) !n
a2) !n / n!
b) n! - !n
c) n * !(n-1)